# Bootstrap on GH-Pages

Tags: bootstrap-4, github-pages, web-development-server

I have had a personal webpage that I host on github-pages for years. That is simple HTML structure and works just fine on gh-pages.

Recently I found a cool website template on bootstrap (https://bootstrapmade.com/) that I'd love to use on my github pages. But when I try to use this template on github pages. It just doesn't work!

What is the best way to use bootstrap templates from https://bootstrapmade.com/ to github pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used a template from **Bootstrap Made** but you can take a look at [this repository](https://github.com/amogh3892/amogh3892.github.io) on Github, which is using a **Bootstrap Made** template and the **Github Pages**.

You basically need to upload the files just like you did with your previous template. For more complex stuff, I would recommend to use [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) or [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) to host your code through the **Github Pages**.

Comment: thank you for sharing! It is useful